# Jwplayer two levels of play button for Chrome

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have the same web page with a jwplayer (version 6) on it on two different hosts (playing a live stream).

On the remote host the screen is greyed slightly and the initial white circle with triangle play button needs to be clicked first. Then a second less greyed screen appears with a rectangular horizontal play button. Clicking that loads the stream.

On the streaming server host (that contains the source of the JWPlayer javascript and streams) I only get the second play button.

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
autostart: 'false', 
allowfullscreen: 'true', 
width: '320', 
height: '260', 
image: 'http://x.x.com/thumbnails/live1.jpg?v=8', 
abouttext: 'test new name', 
base: 'http://x.x.com/jwplayer6/', 
fallback: 'false', 
primary: 'html5', 
 sources: [{ file: 'rtmp://streamx.x.com/live/70922905live' }, { file: 'http://streamx.x.com:1935/live/70922905live/playlist.m3u8'}] 
});
```

Why is this, can I have just the one play button on the remote host? I found I can't start the playback with .play() unless I am on the second level of playbutton.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This was down to chrome. Chrome now tries to stop what it thinks are Ads playing immediately. So it provides the greying and the play button when the javascript that is running the flash is running on another server.

Disable this behaviour with:
Chrome settings -> advanced -> content settings -> plugins -> run all plugin content

http://arstechnica.co.uk/information-technology/2015/06/google-chrome-will-soon-intelligently-block-auto-playing-flash-ads/